# Switch between two views by clicking on a menu tab without any page refresh

Tags: views, 7

I have created two views on my custom content type as two different blocks. I want to place them in a new page say /node/47. In node/47 there are two tabs...on clicking one of them view 1 appears and on clicking another on of them view 2 appears while view1 goes away...by default any of the view can appear on the page when its first visited..i do not want any page refresh to take place

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the [Quick Tabs](http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs) module.

> The Quick Tabs module allows you to create blocks of tabbed content,
>   specifically views, blocks, nodes* and other quicktabs*. You can
>   create a block on your site containing multiple tabs with
>   corresponding content. Clicking on the tabs makes the corresponding
>   content display instantly, using jQuery. With the 6.x-2.x branch, this
>   can be done in either ajax or non-ajax mode:

Comment: the Quick Tabs works like magic...thanks a lot for pointing me in this direction...i was about to write custom js and ajax for this...